# query to find out multiple data entry

Tags: sql, duplicate-data

I have a child table and for a particular entity (Foreign Key), data may have been feeded more than once. How can I find all the rows having multiple data in it. 
For eg, for the below table, I want to retrieve records where we have multiple data in city (Berlin, Seol and Frankfurt):

```
| Name       | Product | City
---------------------------------
| John       | Item A  | London
| Muller     | Item A  | Berlin Berlin Berlin
| Abby       | Item A  | Auckland
| Roy        | Item A  | Delhi
| Charles    | Item X  | Seol Seol Seol Seol
| Schultz    | Item X  | Munchen
| Walter     | Item X  | New York
| Noah       | Item X  | Mexico
| Dickens    | Item X  | Madrid
| Bill       | Item Z  | Frankfurt Frankfurt
| Arthur     | Item Z  | Warsow
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name
, Product
, City
COUNT(*) as NumRecs
FROM dbo.Table
GROUP BY Name
, Product
, City
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Please, add some explanation. Code-only answers are (sometimes) good, but Code+Explanation answers are (most of times) better.